# how do you scale the ZK-framework?

Tags: scalability, zk

I'm currently working on a project where we migrate a web application, which uses the ZK-framework, to a eucalyptus cloud enviroment, but we wonder how we can make the framework scalable. Is it even scalable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, ZK can be scaled well. One of ZK's clients is building an application targeting 20 millions users. The application passed the stress test a couple months ago.

Like JSF or other server-side solutions, ZK has to hold the states of UI at the servers (unless you take the pure-client approach). It means you have to make the states serializable if you'd like to support failover. You could refer to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Clustering for more information.

On the other hand, the access of UI states in one browser window won't block the acess of another browser window. The access is done in fully parallel. The bottleneck, from our consulting experiences, is usually from the backend services rather than UI. Anyway, depending on your targeting scale and the application's complexity, there are several architectural approaches, such as using a load-balance dispatcher in front of UI layer, running UI layer in a separated server, etc.

I am not familiar with eucalyptus, so not sure if anything worth to notice.